# Replace equal sub-strings with different words

Tags: python, replace

I have a string:

```
s = '96 ST MARY ST'
```

Now the first occurrence of `'ST'` is *Saint*, and the second occurrence is *Street* i.e. Saint Mary Street.

I want to replace the first `ST` with Saint, and the second `ST` with Street. For this I tried to use `find()` and `rfind()`:

```
# index of ST
ind = s.find('ST')

s[ind:(ind+2)] = 'Saint'

# index of last ST
ind2 = s.rfind('ST')

s[ind2:(ind2+2)] = 'Street'

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

I don't know how to get around this.

Is there a way to extract these sub-strings somehow and replace them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two replacement:

```
s = s.replace("ST", "Saint", 1).replace("ST", "Street", 1)
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this case insensitive?

Comment: In such a simple way I think not, we should use regex.

Answer (score 1):

You might be OK with using `re.sub` along with its count parameter, to target the first replacement:

```
s = '96 ST MARY ST'
print(s)
out = re.sub(r'\bST\b', 'Saint', s, 1)
print(out)
out = re.sub(r'\bST\b', 'Street', s)
print(out)
```

This prints:

```
96 ST MARY ST
96 Saint MARY ST
96 Street MARY Street
```

However, while the above coincidentally works for your exact sample input, there are many edge cases where this would fail.  It assumes that `Saint` comes before `Street`, and this may not always be the case, nor may there always be only two occurrences of `ST`.

Comment: I will be feeding it into the function with the condition `if first word and last word are 'ST': send to function`

Answer (score 0):

A simple way, assuming there are always 2 occurences of 'ST':

```
p1, p2, _ = s.split('ST')

res = f"{p1}Saint{p2}Street"
```

If your input strings happen to be more complexes, you should go for [regex](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html) (as Tim Biegeleisen proposed)